# How geocoder.geocode() works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

My only question is, if browser does not support **cross domain AJAX request** than How google map api works to get the data.

How following code works ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
   }
});
</script>
```

**what geocoder.geocode does internally ?**

EDIT:
Ok they are including **http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/8/main.js**

**can anyone tell me where they are using JSONP in their JS Code ?**

Comment: open console and go to referenced library, so you can check the code added by google maps library.

Comment: Minified code is *really* well-readable...

Comment: i had beautified it through http://www.javascriptbeautifier.com/ ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It most likely uses JSONp, i.e. it includes a script from the google servers that calls a callback function and passes the response to that function.

Comment: Can you tell me where they are using JSONp in their js code [link](http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/8/main.js) ? i tried but failed.

Comment: Most likely in the `he` function: `a[sb]("script")` which calls `createElement`.